# text of node's inner text and first child nodes text

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have multiple links in page of structure like this:

```
<a ....>
    <b>Text I Need</b>
    Also Text I need
</a>
```

And i want to extract string for example from code above "Text I NeedAlso Text I need"
I successfully extract second part, but I'm not sure how to select text inside b tags as well, currently I'm using this:

```
var link_list = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"/a/text()");
foreach (var link in link_list)
{
   Console.WriteLine(link.InnerText);
}
```

Should i perhaps instead get not text but html of a and remove  tags with regex and extract text then, or is there some other ways?

Comment: This seems to work for me. See http://jsfiddle.net/hmhm5hzb/

Comment: Weird, because for me its just giving part which is not in b tags, however removing '/text()' from xpath solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing `InnerText` property of `<a>` should give you all text nodes at once :

```
var html = @"<a ....>
    <b>Text I Need</b>
    Also Text I need
</a>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var link_list = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/a");
foreach (var link in link_list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(link.InnerText);
}
```

or if you really need to get only direct child text nodes and grand child text nodes, try this way :

```
var link_list = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/a");
foreach (var link in link_list)
{
    var texts = link.SelectNodes("text() | */text()");
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", texts.Select(o => o.InnerText)));
}
```

**output :**

```
Text I Need
Also Text I need
```

Comment: Just realised my mistake was putting '/text()' in Xpath, thanks.